# How to make CollectionView's item loop when scrolling in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using CollectionView to display data by scroll. However, there is a problem that after the data, it scrolls iteratively? **Means after I reach the last element, it will show me the first element again.** I know CarouselView has a property called loop for that. However, for some reason, I don't use CarouselView. This is the code I used:

**PageOne.xaml**

```
<CollectionView x:Name="_data" HeightRequest="115" ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepItemsInView" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" Scrolled="_data_Scrolled">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" SnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" SnapPointsAlignment="Start" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                ...
            </StackLayout>                                                                    
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

**PageOne.xaml.cs**

Do I autorun items in CollectionView

```
....
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4), (Func<bool>)(() =>
{
    _data.ScrollTo(listData.Count + 2, -1, ScrollToPosition.Start, true);
    //return true;
}));
```

**In my code, check the _data_Scrolled event when the last element is reached**

```
private void _data_Scrolled(object sender, ItemsViewScrolledEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.LastVisibleItemIndex + 1 == countHotSeling)
    {
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4), (Func<bool>)(() =>
        {
            _data.ScrollTo(listData.Count - 2, +1, ScrollToPosition.Start, true);
            return true;
        }));
    }    
}
```

When t debug, it actually jumps to the event when the last element is reached. However, it does not loop?

Looking forward to everyone's help. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean you want to loop the item when reaching the last element? Also, could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo?

Comment: Yes. Link github: https://github.com/chimditruvn/Appssss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ​`RemainingItemsThresholdReached​` event to load more items by setting the `​RemainingItemsThreshold`​ parameter when reaching the last item. However, since the items in Collectionview are not listed in order so we can't reach the last element.We only can replicate the `_data`.
Here is the code sample below for your reference:

```
      public Test2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadData();
            _data.RemainingItemsThreshold = 13;
            _data.RemainingItemsThresholdReached += _data_RemainingItemsThresholdReached;
        }


     private async void _data_RemainingItemsThresholdReached(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var monkeyJson = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(monkeyUrl);
            var monkeys = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Monkey[]>(monkeyJson);

            foreach (var monkey in monkeys)
            {
                Monkeys.Add(monkey);
                count++;
            }
            _listProd = Monkeys.ToList();

            _data.ItemsSource = _listProd;
        }
```

Reference link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data#load-data-incrementally